# Images folder on team foundation server not copying to azure on build

Tags: asp.net, azure, tfs

I am developing a .Net aspx application using visual studio 2012 and team foundation server/service paired with Microsoft azure cloud services.

I am able to edit code and check those changes back into TFS, however for some reason the entire /images folder which is important to this web application is no longer moving over to azure when being built.

The images exist in visual studio, can be viewed online on TFS but do not end up on our deployment server.

Have tried renaming the images folder, deleting it, checking new files in etc but still nothing shows in a web browser?

I do not have direct access to the azure account where this app is hosted, only TFS and the code base.

All changes to .aspx and .css files are turning up on azure server without a problem.
I will also say that when checking files in on visual studio it's very fast - almost like the files aren't being uploaded.

My background is in php development so I'm not denying this could well be user error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Visual Studio project, make sure that the files in the images folder are marked as **Build Action = Content** in the properties window.